# SQL nested query returns nothing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a beginner in SQL and am having difficulty understanding the logic query. In this particular problem, I am trying to find the Track that was purchased in California.

Here are the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [InvoiceLine]
(
[InvoiceLineId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[InvoiceId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[TrackId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[UnitPrice] NUMERIC(10,2)  NOT NULL,
[Quantity] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_InvoiceLine] PRIMARY KEY  ([InvoiceLineId]),
FOREIGN KEY ([InvoiceId]) REFERENCES [Invoice] ([InvoiceId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY ([TrackId]) REFERENCES [Track] ([TrackId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE [Invoice]
(
[InvoiceId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[CustomerId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[InvoiceDate] DATETIME  NOT NULL,
[BillingAddress] NVARCHAR(70),
[BillingCity] NVARCHAR(40),
[BillingState] NVARCHAR(40),
[BillingCountry] NVARCHAR(40),
[BillingPostalCode] NVARCHAR(10),
[Total] NUMERIC(10,2)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY  ([InvoiceId]),
FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerId]) REFERENCES [Customer] ([CustomerId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE [Track]
(
[TrackId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Name] NVARCHAR(200)  NOT NULL,
[AlbumId] INTEGER,
[MediaTypeId] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[GenreId] INTEGER,
[Composer] NVARCHAR(220),
[Milliseconds] INTEGER  NOT NULL,
[Bytes] INTEGER,
[UnitPrice] NUMERIC(10,2)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Track] PRIMARY KEY  ([TrackId]),
FOREIGN KEY ([AlbumId]) REFERENCES [Album] ([AlbumId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY ([GenreId]) REFERENCES [Genre] ([GenreId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
FOREIGN KEY ([MediaTypeId]) REFERENCES [MediaType] ([MediaTypeId]) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

Here is what I've tried.

```
SELECT T.name
FROM Track T, InvoiceLine L
WHERE T.trackid=L.trackid AND
L.invoiceid IN (SELECT I.invoiceid
FROM Invoice I
WHERE I.billingcity="California");
```

The query returns nothing. What is wrong with the logic?

Comment: can you give sample data for the tables?

Comment: My best guess is that "California" as a city probably doesn't have very many rows.

Comment: what the result of your sub-query?

Comment: I am currently running this in my terminal and don't know how to display sample data on it. Is there a way I can use an interface like myPHPAdmin running on a free server domain? I have tried using myPHPAdmin but have no luck importing the database. I think the problem is the database is written in sqlite. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's MySQL, install MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I decided to use SQLite Browser. I will try to attack at this problem again since now I have sample data tables. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
      T.name
FROM Track T
      INNER JOIN InvoiceLine L ON T.trackid = L.trackid
      INNER JOIN invoice I ON L.InvoiceId = I.InvoiceId
WHERE I.BillingState = 'California'
```

`Track` joins to `InvoiceLine` which joins to `Invoice`

Please do NOT use the ancient way of joining through the where clause. The simplest trick for this is to disallow any commas between table e.g. note the comma in: `FROM Track T, InvoiceLine L` - avoid those.

I assume you want the state of California held in `BillingState` not a city of that name (if one exists).

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the formatting and also reminding me California is state!